# The difference between MySQL wildcards for granting permissions

Tags: mysql, database, sql-grant, database-permissions

What is the difference between `*`, `%`, `Any` in the username/host fields when granting permissions to a user, and how would the combination of them differ?

For example:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db.* TO '*'@'Any';
```

would this be the same as

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db.* TO 'Any'@'%';
```

*EDIT*: The `Any` field I was thinking of comes from phpMyAdmin. Perhaps it means something different? I have pasted a screenshot below to illustrate what I mean.

[image: User permissions in phpMyAdmin]

Answer (score 1):

The word "any" has no special meaning.

MySQL does not support wildcards in the user name, so the first example is illegal. To grant privileges to an anonymous user from a host called `any` use:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db.* TO ''@'Any';
```

The second example is legal, but it grants privileges to a user called "any" who may connect from any host.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The `Any` field comes from phpMyAdmin apparently, and I updated my answer to illustrate the specific examples I need to understand.